# I'm running opencv code and got this error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, opencv

```
def findGun(outputs,img):
ht , wt , ct = img.shape
bbox = []
classIDs = []
confs = []
for output in outputs:
    for det in outputs:
        scores = det[5:]
        classID = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[classID]
        if confidence > confThreshold:
            w,h = int(det[2]*wt),int(det[3]*ht)
            x , y = int((det[0]*wt) - w/2),int((det[1]*ht) - h/2)
            bbox.append([x,y,w,h])
            classIDs.append(classID)
            confs.append(float(confidence))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "yolo.py", line 46, in 
findGun(outputs,img)
File "yolo.py", line 26, in findGun
if confidence > confThreshold:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Check the size of `confidence`. Use `confidence.shape` for this.